# How to add onclick activity in react js for dynamically created elements

Tags: reactjs

```
<Button variant={inf.variant} onClick={`${inf.click}`}>
```

Like this im asking in this onclick

if.click is a string which is = "()=>handleEdit(data)"

Comment: `onClick` in React is not like `onclick` in HTML, it accepts an actual function, not a string. For example `onClick={handleClick}` or `onClick={() => alert("click")}`

Comment: if you want pass the function to Button component then pass it as a prop like: `<Button propName={functionName} />`

Answer (score 1):

The value of `onClick` should be a function. Not a string.

For example:

```
<button onClick={functionName}> btn </button>
```

or

```
<button onClick={() => { /* code of the function */ }> btn </button>
```